# Error de data binding practicando en angular?

Tags: angular

Estoy empezando a practicar en agular e intentando hacer data binding con interpolacion coloque un video en la carpeta assets y cree un variable que guarde el link del vid, al intentar bindearlo en el component.html cuando quiero compilar la app me tira el siguente error:

"Error: src/app/app.component.html:7:15 - error TS2339: Property 'imagen1' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

7   
~~~~~~~

src/app/app.component.ts:6:16
6   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

× Failed to compile.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete."

Asi hice el data binding, o intente hacerlo mejor dicho (?

`"vid1 = "C:/Users/nicog/Documents/workspace/angular proyects/musicalapp/src/assets/Comenzando.webm" "`   <--- eso en la carpeta app.component.ts

```
"<div class="container mt-4">
  <img src="{{vid1}}" alt="">
</div>"

                           <--- eso en la carpeta app.component.hmtl
```

**EDITADO**

Fichero app.component.ts

```js
import { HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({   
   selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
  export class AppComponent {
    title: string = 'musicalapp';
    myName: string = "Nicolas";
    age: number = 45   myHair(longliness: string, color: string){
      return longliness + " " + color
    };
    vid1: string = "C:/Users/nicog/Documents/workspace/angular proyects/musicalapp/src/assets/Comenzando.webm"
}
```

Comment: Por favor, puedes mostrarnos los dos ficheros completos? el app.component.html y app.component.ts

Por lo que indica el error, debes estar usando la variable imagen1 en el html sin declararla en el ts

Comment: Gracias! este es mi fichero app.component.ts completo
`import { HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title: string = 'musicalapp';

  myName: string = "Nicolas";

  age: number = 45

 myHair(longliness: string, color: string){
   return longliness + " " + color
 };


 vid1: string = "C:/Users/nicog/Documents/workspace/angular proyects/musicalapp/src/assets/Comenzando.webm"
}`

Comment: Necesitaria también el fichero app.component.html completo por favor. Editalo en tu pregunta para añadirlo de igual forma que yo he hecho. Ahí se ve que la variable si la tienes declarada pero no la que te indica el error "imagen1" que debe estar en el html. Por favor, leete [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [lo necesario para un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: El mensaje de error menciona que en tu archivo __app.component.html__ estas intentando acceder a __imagen1__ , por favor valida que esa variable no la estés usando en el HTML ya que no lo tienes definido en tu componente.

Comment: `Segui lo que te indicaron respecto a imagen1.Luego aplicar ruta relativa a assets si no te dara error de tipo GET unsafe C: al convertir el navegador la ruta en un tipo  load URL file:///C:...........>por eso definir a vid1 de esta forma:-->vid1="../../assets/Comenzando.webm"

</video>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="{{videoRelativo}}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
`